# Adding let values together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a tax calculator app with JavaScript and have a problem adding let values.

When trying to add 3 different tax values together, in the console, the answer I always get is the first of the values.

```js
let basicRate,
  higherRate,
  additionalRate;

function calculateTaxDue(grossSalary) {
  if (grossSalary > 150000) {
    basicRate = parseFloat((46351 - 11000) * 0.2).toFixed(2);
    higherRate = parseFloat((150000 - 46351) * 0.4).toFixed(2);
    additionalRate = parseFloat((grossSalary - 150000) *
      0.45).toFixed(2)
    taxDue = parseFloat((basicRate + higherRate +
      additionalRate)).toFixed(2);
  }
}


calculateTaxDue(150001)

console.log(parseFloat(basicRate).toFixed(2));
console.log(parseFloat(higherRate).toFixed(2));
console.log(parseFloat(additionalRate).toFixed(2));

console.log(parseFloat(basicRate + higherRate +
  additionalRate).toFixed(2));
```

Just prints the first value (basicRate) to the console. I'm confused by this.

Apologies for lack of detail first time around.

Thanks

Comment: The code as it is would print `NaN`. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, adding values together doesn't have anything to do with how the variables have been declared (`let`, `var` or `const`). There is no such thing as *"let values"*. If you only "get the first value" then the other two values may be `0`.

Comment: `undefined + undefined + undefined` is `NaN`. What good is a demo that doesn't demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Looks to me like they all print.

Comment: You are getting this result because `basicRate`, `higherRate` and `additionalRate` are **strings**. `basicRate + higherRate +
  additionalRate` produces the string `"7070.2041459.600.45"` and `parseFloat("7070.2041459.600.45").toFixed(2)` the returns `7070.20`. Only use `.toFixed` when you actually want to **display** numbers.

Comment: Aha, brilliant - thank you Felix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this result because `basicRate`, `higherRate` and `additionalRate` are **strings**.

`basicRate + higherRate +
  additionalRate` produces the string `"7070.2041459.600.45"` and `parseFloat("7070.2041459.600.45").toFixed(2)` the returns `7070.20`.

Only use `.toFixed` when you actually want to **display** numbers:

```js
let basicRate,
  higherRate,
  additionalRate;

function calculateTaxDue(grossSalary) {
  if (grossSalary > 150000) {
    basicRate = (46351 - 11000) * 0.2;
    higherRate = (150000 - 46351) * 0.4;
    additionalRate = (grossSalary - 150000) *
      0.45;
    taxDue = basicRate + higherRate +
      additionalRate;
  }
}


calculateTaxDue(150001)

console.log(basicRate.toFixed(2));
console.log(higherRate.toFixed(2));
console.log(additionalRate.toFixed(2));

console.log((basicRate + higherRate +
  additionalRate).toFixed(2));
```

---

Most importantly: Read the documentation of the functions you are using.

- `parseFloat` expects a string as input and returns a number. There is no point in passing a number to it like you do in `parseFloat((46351 - 11000) * 0.2)`.
- `.toFixed` returns a string. Don't use it if you want to actually perform further computations with the number values.

And finally, [don't use floating point values to perform monetary computations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/218196). The results will be incorrect due to rounding errors and loss of precision. Express all numbers as integers.